# How to randomly assign values to a column using Xi proportion for i to I unique values in another column

Tags: r

I want to assign values of 1 or 0 to a column where the number of 1's present is based on a proportion which is determined by the value in another column.

For example, I have 3 different groups each with their on proportion value:

```
df<-data.frame(group=(rep(c("A","B","C"), 10)))
prop.a<-0.2
prop.b<-0.3
prop.c<-0.1
```

I want to randomly assign values to a new column where the number of 1's to 0's maintains the proportion. So that a table of the data looks like this:

```
>table(df$group, df$Proportion)
  0 1
A 8 2
B 7 3
C 9 1
```

And the data looks like this:

```
> df
      group Proportion
1      A          0
2      A          0
3      A          1
4      A          0
5      A          0
6      A          0
7      A          1
8      A          0
9      A          0
10     A          0
11     B          1
12     B          1
13     B          0
14     B          0
15     B          0
16     B          0
17     B          0
18     B          0
19     B          1
20     B          0
21     C          0
22     C          0
23     C          0
24     C          0
25     C          0
26     C          0
27     C          1
28     C          0
29     C          0
30     C          0
```

Any help would be great. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Using library `dplyr`, you can try something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A","B","C"), 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
prop <- list(A = 0.2, B = 0.3, C = 0.1)

library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(proportion = c(rep(0, ceiling(n() * prop[[group[1]]])), rep(1, floor(n() * (1 - prop[[group[1]]])))))
table(df$group, df$proportion)
```

Output is as follows:

```
    0 1
  A 2 8
  B 3 7
  C 1 9
```

Instead of grabbing the first value of the grouped variable vector to index into `prop` list, you can also use `unique` as follows:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(proportion = c(rep(0, ceiling(n() * prop[[unique(group)]])), rep(1, floor(n() * (1 - prop[[unique(group)]])))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any way to make it random so that it doesn't just assign 0 to the first X of any one group?